# Multiplying fractions in safe way c#

Tags: c#, winforms, numeric

I am trying to work out how to work out the total cost of a vehicle repair job in a numerically safe way, avoiding rounding errors. I get the amount of time spent on a job, then multiply it by a constant labour rate value to get the correct amount cost of labour, however it is not working out how it should be. Here is my example when there has been 20 minutes spent on the job.

[image]

This clearly works out wrong as a third of £30 is £10, so how do I avoid the rounding error I am getting?

Here is how I get the total time.

```
TimeSpan totalTime = TimeSpan.Zero;

    foreach (DataRow timeEntry in dhJob.DataStore.Tables[jobTimeCollectionName].Rows)
    {
        DateTime start = Convert.ToDateTime(timeEntry["jobtimestart"]);
        DateTime end = Convert.ToDateTime(timeEntry["jobtimeend"]);
        totalTime += (end - start);
    }

    tb_labourtime.Text = Convert.ToString(Math.Round(totalTime.TotalHours, 2));

    tb_labourtotal.Text = (Convert.ToDouble(tb_labourtime.Text) * Convert.ToInt32(tb_labourrate.Text)).ToString();
```

Any help / advice is appreciated.

Comment: look into the `decimal` type.

Comment: @Alex He is converting the time to a string with only two digits of precision, so no amount of using `decimal` will fix that (but I agree he should be using `decimal` as part of the solution - it's just not the entire solution)

Comment: I think you better provide a way to enter minutes. Although `0.33` may look close it is still `0.0033333...` of from the exact result, which can make a difference in rounding off.

Comment: @MatthewWatson oops. I did an instinctive comment without checking the question well enough.

Comment: `tb_labourtime.Text = Convert.ToString(...); Convert.ToDouble(tb_labourtime.Text)` this is so dirty. Not only does this risk conversion errors but it also is hard to understand and verify to be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you are converting the `totalTime` to a string representation which only has two digits of precision, which is not going to be very accurate.

Secondly, when doing financial calculations, you should generally use the `decimal` type rather than the `double` type, which will give you greater accuracy(although it still isn't completely accurate).

The first thing to do is to use the `totalTime` to calculate the total wages rather than using a converted string value:

```
tb_labourtotal.Text = (totalTime.TotalHours * Convert.ToInt32(tb_labourrate.Text)).ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks very much @MatthewWatson. I did not know of the precision loss when converting to a string. Changed the doubles to decimal and stopped converting the text numeric types and it's much better. Thanks again.